# Snap.load(): display loading progress in a bar

Tags: snap.svg

I'm creating an HTML5 game where most part of the graphics is handled by svg with the help of Snap.svg. I'm facing the problem of loading big images, that causes the app looking freeze.

I thought a solution could be a progress bar displaying the loaded amount, and here comes my problem: Is it possible to fetch loading info from Snap.load function?

Comment: Not afaik, but you could display something animating (like a rotating circle with a gradient etc) until its loaded (you just can't be sure of completion time).

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a lot of time!!